# Complex Number Magnitude

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve $\frac 14$[1 + e$^\left(-j\frac 34\pi\right)]$

First I expand e$^\left(-j\frac 34\pi\right)$, which gives:

cos(-$\frac 34\pi$) + j[sin(-$\frac 34\pi$)]:

-$\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}$ + j(
-$\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2})$:

0

Thereafter it becomes

$\frac 14$[1 + 0] = $\frac 14$

However, the given answer is

$\frac {\sqrt{2}}{4}$ * phase($\frac {\pi}{4}$)

Comment: Why $0$? Your exponential to polar form is correct, but it is non-zero in both real and imaginary parts,

Comment: my mistake, I took j as value of -1, when it should be $\sqrt {-1}$

Comment: Sorry, another question, how do I solve the equation ?

It becomes -$\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}$(1 + j) but I'm not sure how to continue from here

Answer (score 1):

We have

$-\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}+j(-\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2})) \ne 0$

Comment: Sorry, I understand why it's not 0 now. How do I solve the equation ? It becomes -2√222(1 + j) but I'm not sure how to continue from here

Answer (score 0):

When $\text{j}^2=-1$:

$$e^{-\frac{3\pi\text{j}}{4}}=\exp\left(-\frac{3\pi\text{j}}{4}\right)=\cos\left(-\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)+\sin\left(-\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\text{j}=$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\text{j}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\text{j}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{1}{4}\left\{1+e^{-\frac{3\pi\text{j}}{4}}\right\}=\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\text{j}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\approx0.0732233-0.176777 \text{j}$$